# Material UI 1.3.1 text field doesn't have an onKeyPress method

Tags: reactjs, material-design, styling

When I try to have an on on handleKeyPress method on my material UI text field waiting for an enter key to trigger an event, but an onKeyPress isn't supported. Is there any other way to handle an Enter key press on a text field with Material UI?

```
  <TextField
     onChange={(e) => this.handleKeyPress(e)}
  />



handleKeyPress = (e) => {
    if (e.keyCode === 'Enter') {
        this.check(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Must use the keyCode propertie

```
handleKeyPress = (e) => {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        this.check(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: just on an onChange ?

Comment: Ya this isn't working for me. when I try to console.log e or e.keyCode, it gives me undefined for keyCode and for just e an object with all of the values in it null